# Buildozer (python-for-android) error message about python2

Tags: python, kivy, buildozer

Trying to compile an apk using buildozer 0.39 on a Ubuntu 18.04 VM.
I get a strange error:

```
# Run '/usr/bin/python -m pythonforandroid.toolchain create --dist_name=XXXXXX --bootstrap=sdl2 --requirements=python2,kivy,sqlite3,requests,feedparser,html2bbcode --arch armeabi-v7a --copy-libs --color=always --storage-dir="/home/kivy/4Build/XXXXXX/.buildozer/android/platform/build" --ndk-api=21'
# Cwd /home/kivy/4Build/XXXXXX/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android
[ERROR]:   Build failed: python-for-android no longer supports running under Python 2. Either upgrade to Python 3.4 or higher (recommended), or revert to python-for-android 2019.07.08. Note that you *can* still target Python 2 on Android by including python2 in your requirements.
```

The command I use includes the `python2` requirement, but `python-for-android` says its not...

Comment: You are running buildozer using python2. Uninstall it, then install using python3.

Comment: I tried it but did not succeed. I'll try again using another VM that I found [here](https://github.com/zaemiel/kivy-buildozer-installer)..

Comment: The python2 build failed with the new VM too. I'll try to make the app work with python3..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, converting the project to Python 3 and compiling it using the newer VM ([that I found here](https://github.com/zaemiel/kivy-buildozer-installer)) did work!
Still no way to do it with Python 2 though..

Answer (score 0):

I just got the same issue today. I did not have this issue a few days ago. Luckily, I made multiple back-ups of the folders that used to work in the past. My solution is to copy the folder python-for-android from the path of one of the back-ups (yourfoldername)/.buildozer/android/platform and paste it into the new folder/.buildozer/android/platform. Then run buildozer -v android debug deploy run. Everything is working again.

As Mr.inclement commented above, I need to uninstall buildozer and install using python3. I'm not sure how to uninstall buildozer besides deleting the buildozer folder. And then how to install using pyhon3? The instruction is git clone https://github.com/kivy/buildozer.git, cd buildozer, sudo python setup.py install. So in the last step, I need to use sudo python3 setup.py install ? I don't want to mess up what's already working. So I use the python-for-android folder from one of my back-ups.

Comment: I did it using `pip3 uninstall buildozer` and then `pip3 install --user --upgrade buildozer`. I think that somewhere I used sudo too. Also deleted the `~/.buildozer` and `<project>/.buildozer` directories..